# HTTPoison.get() error in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, httpoison

I have the following URL

https://www.michaelkors.com/four-in-one-logo-belt-box-set/_/R-US_39F6LBLY4B?color=0200

And need to get the page body via HTTPoison.get.
The following method gives an timeout error

```
case HTTPoison.get("https://www.michaelkors.com/four-in-one-logo-belt-box-set/_/R-US_39F6LBLY4B?color=0200", []) do
   {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body}} ->
       {:ok, body}
   {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
       {:error, reason}
end
```

For other URL's it works, seems like the error caused due to specific pattern in URL

Comment: I do not think this issue has anything to do with `Elixir`/`HTTPoison`. I get a timeout for this url with plain old good `wget`/`curl` as well.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't have much matter with `Elixir/HTTPoison`. You may need to add header like `Host`, `Origin` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have much matter with Elixir/HTTPoison. The Website had set limits according to request header.

Curl works only with headers like :

`curl 'https://www.michaelkors.com/four-in-one-logo-belt-box-set/_/R-US_39F6LBLY4B?color=0200'  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'   -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2'`

You need to also set these headers in `HTTPoison`.